# How to fire code behind method using onclick but not asp:button OnClick

Tags: html, asp.net, onclick

Im in asp.net and I already have a form that utilizes runat="server". I created another form on the page and I have a method in code behind that I need to run on an onclick event.

Since I already have one form on the page, I can't use an asp:button with runat="server"

What's the best way to get my method to fire using an onclick?

Here's my code behind:

```
    protected void requestSong_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var artist = Request.Form["artist"].ToUpper();
    var song = Request.Form["song"].ToUpper();
    var song_Request = artist + " - " + song;

    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
    con2.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into SONGS values (@REQUESTED_SONGS)", con2);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("REQUESTED_SONGS", song_Request);

    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Here's my aspx:

```
    <form id ="songRequest">
     <p style="color:greenyellow"> Request a song</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Artist" name="artist" id="artist" />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Song Title" name="song" id="song" />
      <button class="button" onclick="" id="requestSongButton" name="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple forms.

Comment: The 2nd form is not an asp.net form, it's an html form

Comment: That does not matter. You cannot have nested forms.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to accomplish what Im asking then? I dont need it to be a form, but I do need to take the text from an input and send it to my method and submit the method

Comment: You can place as many buttons and contrrols on a page you want and only read the ones you need in `requestSong_Click`

Comment: So how would I be able to fire the code behind method using an onclick that isn't an asp.net onclick, which seems to only be able to fire once per page. when I try using the asp:button class again i get an error that says it must be contained in a form.

Comment: @user9175041, check the answer I have just posted. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the approach outlined below to fire code-behind method on clicking the button in second client-side form.

- Make sure that you have `asp:ScriptManager` included in your page just after the first form tag ( this is very important else this approach will not work)
- Include the JavaScript code given below in your page. In this script, `__doPostBack` method is being called which is a standard JavaScript function used by asp.net framework to post back on control events like on button click. This function will only be available if you include asp:ScriptManager in your page.
- Change the markup of the button in client-side form so it has an onclick attribute set
- In your, code-behind in Page_Load event check for the parameters `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` and call the method `requestSong_Click` passing null for both its parameters ( note: you must not be using sender or e in your button click else this will not work)

*JavaScript code to include in page*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postBack(btn) {
         //get data you want to pass to code-behind
         var artist = document.getElementById("artist").value;
         var song = document.getElementById("song").value;
         var arguments = "saveToDb" + "|" + artist + "|" + song;

        __doPostBack('requestSongButton', arguments);
        //you can pass more arguments using a comma-delimited or pipe-delimited list of values
        //to the second parameter in above method
    }
</script>
```

*Markup needed for button in client-side form*

```
<button class="button" onclick="" id="requestSongButton" name="Submit" 
                          onclick="doPostBack(this); return false;">Submit</button>
```

*C# code-behind to handle submit by client-side form button*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Page.IsPostBack)
     {
       if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "requestSongButton" && 
                Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"].IndexOf("saveToDb") = 0)
        {
          //code that executes on click of requestSongButton in second form
           requestSong_Click(null, null);
        }
     }
}
```

*C# code to get posted values for client-side form button postback*

```
protected void requestSong_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   string artist;
   string song;

   //you must always pass null for e and sender if posting from client-side form button
   if (sender == null && e == null) {
    var arguments = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
    if (arguments != null && arguments != String.Empty) {

     //split the | delimited string to an array
     Dim argumentsArray as String() = arguments.Split(New Char() {
      "|"
      c
     });

     //now get values of artist textbox and song textbox
     //note that artist index is 1 and soung index is 2
     //due to the sequence in which we populated arguments
     //in client-side JavaScript doPostBack function
     artist = argumentsArray[1];
     song = argumwentsArray[2];
    }

   } else {
    artist = Request.Form["artist"].ToUpper();
    song = Request.Form["song"].ToUpper();
   }
   string song_Request = artist + " - " + song;

   SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString);
   con2.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into SONGS values (@REQUESTED_SONGS)", con2);
   cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("REQUESTED_SONGS", song_Request);

   cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

  //more of your code follows
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in my markup when I include ScriptManager "Control 'Scriptmanager1' of type 'ScriptManager' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server"

Comment: This is what I changed the markup to for my form     `<form id="songRequestForm">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server"/>
            <p style="color:greenyellow"> Request a song</p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Artist" name="artist" id="artist" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Song Title" name="song" id="song" />
            <button class="button" onclick="doPostBack(this); return false;" id="requestSongButton" name="Submit" />
     </form>`

Comment: You need to place the RadScriptManager inside the first form which has a runat="server" attribute. I have mentioned to include it after the first form tag in my answer and you included it in second form tag.

Comment: ok that seems to have worked, but Im getting a new error "Line: 88
Error: 'doPostBack' is undefined" when I try to click the submit button. I included the <script> tag in the header

Comment: Can you post the code for JavaScript that you have included with opening and closing tags?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
    function postBack(btn) {
        __doPostBack('requestSongButton', "saveToDb");
        //you can pass more arguments using a comma-delimited list of values
        //to the second parameter in above method
    }
</script>`

Comment: Look at this video to see how to put your script correctly : https://www.screencast.com/t/innHYI7hEz6. This sample runs perfectly on my end.

Comment: The second form should be outside the first form. If you are putting second form within first form then it will NOT work.

Comment: Got it, needed to change the onclick= to postBack instead of doPostBack

Comment: Ok great. The onclick attribute is clearly shown in markup code in my answer. May be you forgot that step.

Comment: Im wondering if there is a way to store the form input into a variable in codebehind? It's not a runat="server" form so Request.Form[] doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Pass whatever data you need as a comma-delimited list for the second parameter to `__doPostBack` in your JavaScript code. Then, in code-behind you can get this custom data using `Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]`.

Comment: You can modify your button click event to include logic for getting `Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]` if `Request.Form["artist"] == null`.

Comment: Forgive me, this is all new territory for me. I'm still not sure how I would pass and store the values of the form input using this method. In the __doPostBack function, I tried adding the input ID after the "saveToDB" argument, but the value isn't getting stored anywhere from what I can see. I hate to ask for it, but could you give me a code example to help guide me please?

Comment: Try the latest code I have posted. This should solve your new issue. I have provided detailed explanation through comments in the code posted.

Comment: Amazing, works exactly as I intended now. Thanks so much